# CCBMemberVariableAssigner callbacks disfunctional for custom CCTableViewCell in CocosBuilder

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

my goal is to design a CCTableViewCell via CocosBuilder
and load it via CCBReader.

My steps so far:

I added a new non-fullscreen CCNode **TestCell.ccb** in cocosbuilder,
set the root's custom class to `TestCell`
and added a CCSprite as the roots child while setting
it's *doc-root-var* to `bg`.

My problem: after implementing a loader `TestCellLoader`
as well as the Cell `TestCell` the callback-function
`TestCell::onAssignCCBMemberVariable` is not called at all.

What I tried:
Using a `CCLayerLoader` instead of a `CCNodeLoader` worked for me so far,
this is the first time I'm using a `CCNodeLoader` so maybe I missed
a crucial point.

Thank you,
Ciao!
Ben

Here are the codes:

**TestCellLoader.h**

```cpp
#include <cocos2d.h>
#include "cocos-ext.h"

#include "TestCell.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace cocos2d::extension;

    class TestCellLoader : public CCNodeLoader
    {
    public:
        CCB_STATIC_NEW_AUTORELEASE_OBJECT_METHOD(TestCellLoader, create);

    protected:
        CCB_VIRTUAL_NEW_AUTORELEASE_CREATECCNODE_METHOD(TestCell);

        virtual CCNode* loadCCNode(CCNode *, CCBReader * pCCBReader);
    };
```

**TestCellLoader.cpp**

```cpp
#include "TestCellLoader.h"

CCNode * TestCellLoader::loadCCNode(CCNode * pParent, CCBReader * pCCBReader)
{
    CCLOG("TestCell::loadCCNode");
    CCNode * ccNode = this->createCCNode(pParent, pCCBReader);
    return ccNode;
}
```

**TestCell.h**

```cpp
class TestCell : public CCTableViewCell, public CCNodeLoaderListener, public CCBMemberVariableAssigner
    {
    public:
        TestCell();
        virtual ~TestCell();

        static TestCell *create();

        virtual bool init();
        virtual bool initWithBG(CCSprite* bg);

        static TestCell* cellWithBG(CCSprite* bg);

        // ccbuilder callbacks

        virtual bool onAssignCCBMemberVariable(cocos2d::CCObject * pTarget, const char * pMemberVariableName, cocos2d::CCNode * pNode);

        virtual void onNodeLoaded(cocos2d::CCNode * pNode, cocos2d::extension::CCNodeLoader * pNodeLoader);


    private:
        CC_PROPERTY(CCSprite*, bg, Bg);
    };
```

**TestCell.m**

```cpp
   #include "TestCell.h"

    using namespace cocos2d;
    using namespace cocos2d::extension;

        TestCell::TestCell(){}
        TestCell::~TestCell(){}


    #pragma mark creation

        TestCell* TestCell::create(){
            TestCell *pRet = new TestCell();
            pRet->init();
            pRet->autorelease();
            return pRet;
        }

        bool TestCell::init(){
            return true;
        }

        bool TestCell::initWithBG(CCSprite* bg){
            return true;
        }

        TestCell* TestCell::cellWithBG(CCSprite* bg){
            return new TestCell;
        }

    #pragma mark - synthesize

        void TestCell::setBg(cocos2d::CCSprite *sprite){
            this->bg = sprite;
        }

        CCSprite* TestCell::getBg(){
            return this->bg;
        }


    #pragma mark - ccbuilder callbacks

        void TestCell::onNodeLoaded(cocos2d::CCNode * pNode,  cocos2d::extension::CCNodeLoader * pNodeLoader)
        {
            CCLOG("TestCell::onNodeLoaded");
        }

         bool TestCell::onAssignCCBMemberVariable(CCObject* pTarget, const char* pMemberVariableName, CCNode* pNode)
         {
             CCLOG("TestCell::onAssignCCBMemberVariable %s", pMemberVariableName);
             return false;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used a `CCLayer` as **TestCell.ccb**'s *Root object type*. Since when you are creating a new ccb file, `CCLayer` is as default option.

And this is why you use a `CCLayerLoader` instead of a `CCNodeLoader` worked.

So change your **TestCell.ccb**'s *Root object type* to `CCNode`, this maybe works.